# How can I locate my house/horses in a creative flat world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I died on a creative flat world when I fell off the world. I thought I would just respawn in my house but no, it turns out I never actually slept in my bed nor made a beacon, and my spawn point was not near my house.

I would just rebuild, but I also have over a hundred horses there that I don't want to lose as they have sentimental meaning to me. I also did not write down the coordinates.

Is there a way to find my horses? ( They are all named, and I was wondering if that helps at all)

Comment: Have you lost horses, or houses? It's hard to tell from your question.

Comment: I think they're saying they lost their house location, and since their horses are at their house they've lost them too and wants to get them back. @Penkat did you happen to write coordinates down anywhere?

Comment: Yea, but might be worthwhile waiting for him to edit

Comment: Spawning new horses in creative mode is a matter of seconds.

Comment: They have sentimental meaning.

Comment: if it's a superflat world in creative mode then flying up to a high level where you can see as much of the ground before it disappears will make it easier for you to spot structures. i'd also go about crafting some maps so that you can track your progress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you can recover your horses (and house)!**

There is a very simple command that allows you to do this.

```
/tp @p @e[name=INSERT]
```

In the command, replace INSERT with the name of one of your horses. It will teleport you to it.

If you can't remember the name of any horses, use this command:

```
/tp @p @e[c=1,type=horse]
```

This will teleport you to the nearest horse in your world.

Comment: Since the nearest horse is unlikely to be one of *that* herd, I guess teleporting to a bed, or other block unique to the house would be more likely to help.

Comment: @ pagie_ It's not working. Does this work for all editions and updates? I typed in /tp @p @e[name=Zane] Is there a formatting problem with this?

Comment: Scratch that. It worked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! (Penkat gets up and does happy dance) Thank you so much!!!!!!!!1

Comment: @Penkat Why don't you accept my answer (select the green check mark). It shows that this answer works.

Comment: @SF. Well, horses aren't common in flat worlds...